# React Native Loading not appears

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing a React app where I have to load map data from the server on the home page. It takes a small amount of time when loading data from the server. I want to display a spinner when the data called. I 'm using a spinner component from react native, but I don't know how to display that spinner when the fetch api is triggered.

```
    state = {
    loading: true,
  };
 _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    try {..
      await this.setState({
        map: true,
        loading: false,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ loading: false });}
  };
       renderMap = () => {
return (
      {this.state.loading ? (
            <Spinner color="#58abc8"
              visible={this.state.loading}
              animation="fade" />):
             (<Modal isVisible={this.state.map } >
            ...
            </Modal>
            )}  
           )}
```

on my case here loading not appear and map appear after a while

Answer (score 0):

Set `loading:true` before you start the async API operation, then set it back to `false` when done.

```
 _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    try {
      await this.setState({
        map: true,
        loading: true, // <-- true!
      });

      // do your api call here
      // const data = await .......
      
      // now complete, set loading to false
      this.setState({ loading: false });

    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ loading: false });}
  };
```

Comment: it still the same (loading not appear)

Comment: Can you show your full async call?